# How to do unit-testing of TypeScript in a Visual Studio 2019 ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I've followed the instructions from Microsoft as found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/unit-testing-javascript-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019&tabs=mocha). Writing TypeScript, compiling to JavaScript, debugging the TypeScript all works fine (although not with Firefox), but Mocha TypeScript unit-tests that I add will not be picked up by the Test Explorer.

The error that is shown in the Tests output pane is

```
Log level is set to Informational (Default).
Test data store opened in 0,072 sec.
---------- Starting test discovery ----------
Processing: d:\Dropbox\projects\MemoryLane\playground\AspNetCoreWebApplication1\tests\UnitTest1.js
Using default Mocha settings
Test discovery error: Error: Cannot find module 'd:\Dropbox\projects\MemoryLane\playground\AspNetCoreWebApplication1\tests\UnitTest1.js'
Require stack:
- d:\Dropbox\projects\MemoryLane\playground\AspNetCoreWebApplication1\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js
- d:\Dropbox\projects\MemoryLane\playground\AspNetCoreWebApplication1\node_modules\mocha\index.js
- C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\NODEJSTOOLS\TESTADAPTER\TestFrameworks\mocha\mocha.js
- C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\NODEJSTOOLS\TESTADAPTER\TestFrameworks\find_tests.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:893:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at d:\Dropbox\projects\MemoryLane\playground\AspNetCoreWebApplication1\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:436:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (d:\Dropbox\projects\MemoryLane\playground\AspNetCoreWebApplication1\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:433:14)
    at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\NODEJSTOOLS\TESTADAPTER\TestFrameworks\mocha\mocha.js:47:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\NODEJSTOOLS\TESTADAPTER\TestFrameworks\mocha\mocha.js:41:33 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'd:\\Dropbox\\projects\\MemoryLane\\playground\\AspNetCoreWebApplication1\\node_modules\\mocha\\lib\\mocha.js',
    'd:\\Dropbox\\projects\\MemoryLane\\playground\\AspNetCoreWebApplication1\\node_modules\\mocha\\index.js',
    'C:\\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\\2019\\COMMUNITY\\COMMON7\\IDE\\EXTENSIONS\\MICROSOFT\\NODEJSTOOLS\\TESTADAPTER\\TestFrameworks\\mocha\\mocha.js',
    'C:\\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\\2019\\COMMUNITY\\COMMON7\\IDE\\EXTENSIONS\\MICROSOFT\\NODEJSTOOLS\\TESTADAPTER\\TestFrameworks\\find_tests.js'
  ]
} in d:\Dropbox\projects\MemoryLane\playground\AspNetCoreWebApplication1\tests\UnitTest1.js
Discovered 0 test cases.
No test is available in d:\Dropbox\projects\MemoryLane\playground\AspNetCoreWebApplication1\AspNetCoreWebApplication1.csproj. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
No test is available in d:\Dropbox\projects\MemoryLane\playground\AspNetCoreWebApplication1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\AspNetCoreWebApplication1.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
========== Test discovery finished: 0 Tests found in 4,9 sec ==========
```

So it seems that regular TypeScript is transpiled to JavaScript, but the TypeScript unit-tests are not.

When I setup a Node.js project everything works fine. It's an ASP.NET Core project combined with TypeScript unit-tests that is not working. And according to the documentation it should be possible and I would really like to combine a C# backend with a TypeScript frontend.

Any ideas what's missing?

Comment: I had a similar challenge, but I'm curios, can you share you tsconfig.json file?

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the same tutorial from Microsoft documentation (as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/unit-testing-javascript-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019&tabs=mocha#write-unit-tests-for-aspnet-core)). So this is how I structure my project.

I have the `tsconfig.json` file definition below:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "outDir": "Test",
    "module": "CommonJS"
  },
  "include": [
    "scripts/src/**/*",
    "scripts/unitTests/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

And, in my project manifest.  I have the `<JavaScriptTestRoot>` value.

[image]

Lastly, my project structure below

[image]

In my Test Explorer, `My Test Sample` is discovered.

[image]